# jQuery: How to get DIV to slide-off the screen and another to slide in?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile, slide, css-animations

I've built a web-application which scales down to a mobile-friendly version using CSS @media queries.

I would like to have a button to switch between two main content displaying DIVs.

When page loads, using @media queries, the other one gets hidden via `display: none;`

When a button is clicked, I want it to show and the visible one to hide, which I have currently done already.

But I would like to animate this process, which I'd like to have working smoothly on mobile devices.

But I can not figure out how **jquerymobile** does this already, which works perfectly.

What do I need to do to get a panel (div) to slide-off from the left and another one to slide in from the right just like mobilejquery using non-mobile jquery?

Example: http://m.stanford.edu/
Here when a list item is clicked, it slides off and another one slides in.

Thank you.

Comment: It's fairly easy if you load the contents of both DIVs at the same time. You could then have a container DIV which has the properties `overflow: hidden` and `position: relative`. Inside this container you'd have a "viewport" DIV which would have the property `position: absolute`. You'd place the two content DIVs inside the viewport area and whenever you want to slide to the other content simply use jQuery's `animate()` method on the viewport DIV.

Comment: Hi @kjetilh. Thank you for your comment, I really appreciate the explanation. However I don't think this would work because .animate() is not really hardware supported whereas all jquery mobile animations for panel slides are smooth thanks to acceleration?

Comment: I'm not sure how jQuery mobile does it, but another possibility is perhaps CSS3 transitions which should yield better performance but they are hardly as supported as jQuery effects (cross-browser compatible). Not sure what you're refering to when you say 'acceleration'. Does it not makes sense that jQuery Mobile uses jQuery animations? :p

Comment: Hello again @kjetilh! Apparently jQuery Mobile uses different kind of animations (the nicer, css based version) which use "hardware acceleration", which in turn means smooth animations like on a desktop machine. Without it, all the animations appear super slow and chunky and bulky on mobile devices. I think @abbood's suggestions below are good, so let's give them a good reading. ;-)

Comment: Right, interesting. If the mobile browsers support this then great, I should have a closer look at the `transform` CSS property when I have time myself. Good luck :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

the main function that can help you do hardware accelerated animations using HTML5/css/javascript is the [-webkit-transform: translate3d](https://www.webkit.org/blog/386/3d-transforms/) css rule that *translates* the slides’ horizontal (x) position to the left or right:

**translate3d(x, y, z), translateZ(z)**

*Move the element in x, y and z, and just move the element in z. Positive z is towards the viewer. Unlike x and y, the z value cannot be a percentage.*

Follow this excellent [tutorial](http://mobile.smashingmagazine.com/2012/06/21/play-with-hardware-accelerated-css/) that shows you how to slide full screen divs in any mobile device using the above function along with javascript.

For further discussion about hardware acceleration with html5, see [this](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/html5/) article.